# How to reduce height of a View in a List in SwiftUI for iOS 16

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, ios16

How do you reduce the height of a View in List in SwiftUI for iOS 16?

I was using this method with `defaultMinListRowHeight` set to zero, but iOS 16 adds more adding than previous versions.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var numbers = 1...10
    var body: some View {
        List
        {
            ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                Text(String(number))
            }
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73588883/7129318) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Set your desired height to your `Text` and `List` will follow that height only.

```
var body: some View {
    List
    {
        ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
            Text(String(number))
                .frame(height: 15)// Set your desired height
        }
    }
    .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
    .padding()
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it won't follow accessibility sizing for larger fonts.